# Program gives errors using strings in array

Tags: c++

I am creating an employee structure, with an array. However, it keeps returning this error.
The program is supposed to allow the user to enter an id number and validate, which already works. Then it is supposed to allow the user to search for a value inside the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct Employee
{
    int idNum;
    double payRate;
    string firstName, lastName;
};

int main()
{
    int error;
    const int SIZE = 5;
    Employee employee[SIZE];
    for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; ++k)
    {
        employee[k].idNum = 0;
        employee[k].payRate = 0;
    }
    for(int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
    {
        error = 0;
        cout << "Enter the employee's id number " << endl;
        int tempId;
        cin >> tempId;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            if (employee[i].idNum == tempId)
                error = 1;
        }
        while(error == 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter a new id number " << endl;
            cin >> employee[count].idNum;
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                error = 0;
                if(employee[i].idNum == employee[count].idNum)
                    error = 1;

            }

        }
        cout << "Enter the employee's pay rate " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].payRate;
        cout << "Enter the employee's first name " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].firstName;
        cout << "Enter the employee's last name " << endl;
        cin >> employee[count].lastName;

    }
    int choice;
    cout << "Enter 1 to search for an employee by id number, enter 2 to search by last name, and enter 3 to search by pay " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        int idNumC;
        cout << "Enter an id number ";
        cin >> idNumC;
        for(int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
        {
            if(employee[count].idNum == idNumC)
                cout << employee[count].idNum;
        }
    }
    if(choice == 2)
    {
        string name;
        cout << "Enter the employee's last name " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        for(int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
        {
            if(strcmp(employee[count].lastName, name) == 0)
                cout << "ID number: "<< employee[count].idNum << " First name: " << employee[count].firstName << " Last Name: " << employee[count].lastName << " Hourly Pay: " << endl;
        }
    }
    if(choice == 3)
    {
        int nam;
        cout << "Enter the employee's pay rate " << endl;
        cin >> nam;
        for(int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count)
        {
            if(employee[count].payRate == nam)
                cout << "ID number: "<< employee[count].idNum << " First name: " << employee[count].firstName << " Last Name: " << employee[count].lastName << " Hourly Pay: " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I get

> ```
> 76:41: error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka 
> std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int 
> strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
> ```

How can I fix this error? Thank you for your time.

Comment: 1. Minimal example... please Minimal!   2. `std::string::c_str()`   3. don't use strcmp with std::string, you can use `==`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two string with `==` so i should you `if(employee[count].lastName==name)`  instead of `if(strcmp(employee[count].lastName, name) == 0)`

But if you want use strcmp try

`if(strcmp(employee[count].lastName.c_str(), name.c_str()) == 0)`